# No transparancy when rendering

Tags: animation, export, import, compositing-nodes, transparency

I imported a video file with a greenscreen backround.  I was able to remove the green and acheive transparency. However when I render I still see the green screen.  Even though I don't see it in the compositor.  Help?

Comment: Do you expect others to guess how you set up your nodes and render settings? Please edit your question and add more information and images that show what you did.

Comment: Maybe in the Properties panel > Output > Post Processing, enable the Compositing option?

Comment: https://ibb.co/p4BrJR3.    There is a photo.  And I did have compositor checked in post proccessing @moonboots

Comment: but you haven't plugged your Keying node in the Composite node (which is the Compositor's Output)